# Set name to UILabel as label1, label2 and so on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to set name to UILabel as label1,label2,label3 and so on. For that i don't want to write code for label1,label2,... Now i am using this method.

```
 UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
 UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
 UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
 .....
```

But it's not a good method. I only want to write a single line of code for all labels.
How can i implement this? Is it possible to use %d along with label.
Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create labels with same frame???

Comment: @Reformer : I am adding these labels to uitabelview cells.

Comment: Simply create custom UITableviewCell and add your UILabel statically (Using nib) yeah either dynamically(using code).

Answer (score 2):

just set tag of label and get data by using tag

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
label.tag = i;
[self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tag of Label to differentiate from other instance. there is no such logic you are looking and it is not suggestible to differentiate objects.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420)];
     label.tag = i;
     [self.view addSubview:label];
```

}

```
if ([self.view viewWithTag:i]) {
    [(UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] setText:@"Update Text"];
}
```